# How to create mysql joins in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In Core PHP and MYSQL My code is so far

```
$columns="  wine_sale.code,
            launch_unit - order_unit AS unit, wine_sale.price, wine_details.colour, wine_details.vintage, wine_details.grower, wine_details.name, wine_details.region, wine_details.size, wine_sale.status, wine_size.size_name, wine_sale.discount, wine_sale.OWC, wine_sale.pack_size, wine_sale.ID, wine_note.details_show ";
$tables="wine_sale 
            INNER JOIN wine_details ON wine_sale.code = wine_details.code 
            INNER JOIN wine_region ON wine_details.region = wine_region.region_name 
            INNER JOIN wine_size ON wine_details.size = wine_size.size_code 
            LEFT JOIN wine_note ON MID(wine_details.code,1,LENGTH(wine_details.code)-1) = wine_note.details_code ";

$query = "SELECT $columns FROM $tables WHERE launch_unit - order_unit>0  AND wine_sale.includewine = 1 ORDER BY wine_region.region_order,wine_details.grower,wine_details.vintage,wine_details.name,wine_details.size ";
```

In Zend Framework 2 I am trying to write same code inside database table gateway my code is so far

```
$select->columns(array(new Expression('launch_unit - order_unit AS unit'),'code', 'launch_unit', 'order_unit', 'price','status', 'discount', 'OWC', 'pack_size', 'ID'))
->join('wine_details', 'wine_sale.code = wine_details.code',array('colour','vintage','grower','name','region','size'))
->join('wine_region', 'wine_details.region = wine_region.region_name')
->join('wine_size', 'wine_details.size = wine_size.size_code',array('size_name'))
->join('wine_note', new Expression('MID(wine_details.code,1,LENGTH(wine_details.code)-1) = wine_note.details_code'),array('details_show'),'left');
 $condition = 'launch_unit - order_unit>0 '.$critere.' AND wine_sale.includewine = 1';
$select->where($condition);
$select->order('wine_region.region_order','wine_details.grower','wine_details.vintage','wine_details.name','wine_details.size');
```

Can any one please suggest what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error that you got ?